# Viewing edge property data issue in ArcadeDB

Tags: sql, graph-databases, arcadedb

I recently migrated over to Arcadedb from Orientdb.  I'm having some issues viewing the values of edge properties.

Having typed in these commands (#632:2 is a correct rid for a ViewIncludes edge):

```
CREATE PROPERTY ViewIncludes.order INTEGER;
UPDATE #632:2 SET order = 1;
SELECT from `ViewIncludes` WHERE @rid = #632:2
```

I can't then see the order property in the result under Properties (graph view), nor is it an option in the label drop down nor does it appear in the json result.  When I go to the database schema it does show a property called 'order'.

The purpose of this property is to order the returned vertices.

It worked fine in OrientDB.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Congrats on your porting from OrientDB to ArcadeDB!

First of all, to add a property to an edge, you don't need to define a property. This is valid with both OrientDB and ArcadeDB.

What'd the result of this command?

```
UPDATE #632:2 SET order = 1;
```

Little thing, with both OrientDB and ArcadeDB you can replace this:

```
SELECT from `ViewIncludes` WHERE @rid = #632:2
```

Into this:

```
SELECT from #632:2
```

Comment: Thank you.  The result of 'UPDATE #632:2 SET order = 1;' is 'count 1'.  However, this is going to be one of those head scratches because redoing it again to copy the result for you (which is the same result as before)... and it's all working.  ????!!  I went round in circles before so have absolutely no idea why it wasn't working before.  Thanks so much!  I can occasionally have this way with computers.

Comment: I've worked out why it wasn't working before.  Sorry, really stupid dozy moment.  I was using my UI to test the order of the fields using a button sequence that's also deleting and adding the edges.